# How to query token transfers like etherscan.io?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, etherscan

Look at [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d#tokentxns).

We are able to see tx, from, to, value etc... How is etherscan achieving this? I badly need this kind of functionality in my app. **How can I list token transfers for a ERC20 contract?**

Note, do not suggest me etherscan api etc, I need to this with web3js or other ethereum approaches.

Answer (score 2):

[Contract Events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events):

The ERC20 specification defines events such as Transfer that will be "logged" when a token is transferred from one address to another; these events contain quite a lot of information.

The [Web3 JS API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3-javascript-app-api) allows you to either look back through past blocks for Events that were logged or to listen for events as new blocks are mined.

Look through a range of blocks

```
// watch for an event with {some: 'args'}
var myEvent = myContractInstance.MyEvent({some: 'args'}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
myEvent.watch(function(error, result){
   ...
});
```

Watch for new events

```
var event = myContractInstance.MyEvent({valueA: 23} [, additionalFilterObject])

// watch for changes
event.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

The details that can be found in the returned event object(s)

```
Object - An event object as follows:

**address**: String, 32 Bytes - address from which this log originated.
**args**: Object - The arguments coming from the event.
**blockHash**: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this log was in. null when its pending.
**blockNumber**: Number - the block number where this log was in. null when its pending.
**logIndex**: Number - integer of the log index position in the block.
**event**: String - The event name.
**removed**: bool - indicate if the transaction this event was created from was removed from the blockchain (due to orphaned block) or never get to it (due to rejected transaction).
**transactionIndex**: Number - integer of the transactions index position log was created from.
**transactionHash**: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the transactions this log was created from.
```

<sub>[source](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#callback-return)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, but when I get old logs, which is what I need, I am seeing `transactionHash` is `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` for all logs, is this intended? All I want is that `hash`...